# Optimal retransmission algorithm for a broadcast channel

Tags: algorithm, broadcast, channel, feedback

I have a number of microcontrollers which can communicate over a broadcast medium (in this case, IR). Each node wants to announce its presence to all the other nodes on a regular basis, but since it's a broadcast medium, two nodes transmitting at the same time will create a collision, and neither message will be transmitted correctly.

To further complicate things, when a node receives an invalid message, it doesn't seem practical to reliably determine if this is due to a collision or due to background noise or weak signal. Also, while node visibility will usually be reflexive (A seeing B means B can see A), it will usually be the case that not all nodes can see all other nodes.

Leaving aside external interference for a moment, it seems like a rational approach is to create timeslots, with each node transmitting in each time slot with a small (and ideally similar between nodes) probability. If there are n nodes that transmit with probability p, then no message will be transmitted (1 - p)<sup>n</sup> of the time; exactly one message will be transmitted n * p * (1 - p)<sup>n-1</sup> of the time, and the remainder of the time there will be a collision. The maximum incidence of successful collisions occurs when each of the n nodes transmits 1/nth of the time, and this results in a fairly stable 38% successful transmissions and 24% collisions; this value changes only slightly with increasing numbers of nodes.

Given that, it would seem we could observe the rate of successful transmissions and/or collisions, and adjust our own transmission rate to try and force them towards their expected values. What I'm not sure about is what the best feedback mechanism to achieve this is, such that everyone ends up with similar probabilities. This also doesn't account for external interference, which will cause us to keep decreasing our transmission rate in a doomed effort to avoid collisions that don't exist.

What is the optimal algorithm - either a refinement of the above or a totally different approach - to maximize the proportion of announcement messages each node can receive without collision?

Comment: Additional clarification: all nodes are aware of all other nodes, and all nodes acknowledge receipt of each message?

Comment: Good point. Not all nodes can see all other nodes at any one time. If nodes are to acknowledge receipt, they'd have to do it over the same broadcast medium.

Comment: Also, I just realised that nodes _will_ be able to detect their own collisions, because they'll see a 'mark' when they're transmitting a 'space'. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I was just going to ask what you meant by *we could observe the rate of successful transmissions*. Having acknowledge messages would help detect additional collisions (or simply dropped messages) not detected by the sender node, but, as you noted, would increase chatter. On the other hand, I don't think you need to decrease transmittion rate? IIRC, [CSMA/CARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance_and_Resolution_using_Priorities) only chooses a random delay on top of the min [interframe spacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interframe_spacing).

Comment: @Groo Since all I'm transmitting is presence messages, I don't need retransmits or throttling - I just need a way to have all nodes be able to send a ping, as frequently as possible. By observing successful transmissions, I mean that we can count the number of complete and valid messages we receive, as well as the number of invalid ones, and use that to tweak our own send rate.

Comment: @NickJohnson: Just to make sure I follow: what you are basically describing is a [slotted aloha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALOHAnet#Slotted_ALOHA) protocol? If not - can you please point to the differences? (I believe it'll help people who are familiar with the protocol understand what you are doing) AFAIK, the general approach to "adjust" the rate of sends is [exponential backoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) on collisions - but it lacks the fairness you are after.

Comment: @amit That does look quite similar to what I was proposing as one possible solution - they even arrive at roughly the same max utilization figure. One difference I can see is that I know ahead of time that every node will want to transmit in every timeslot it can - so I can hopefully pre-emptively avoid that by doing random backoff before I transmit at all. The question is, will naive exponential backoff arrive at optimal (or near optimal) utilization rates? Why do you say exponential backoff lacks fairness?

Comment: @NickJohnson: Optimal is hard, but the expectancy using it is `e^-1`, AFAIK. Slotted Aloha lacks fairness because a node that just sent a msg is resetting its timer back to 0, and the exponential back off starts counting from 0 again, and thus is more likely to send the next msg faster then a node that is "stuck" after some iteration of the exponential back-off. I assume it can be handled by decreasing the timer after a successful send - and not resetting it, but I am not aware of a protocol that does it.

Comment: @NickJohnson: If every node wants to transit data always, you can give each node a specific slot, and make it send the data every `n` slots (assuming you know what `n` is, of course, and you can precalculate it if the network is static) - or am I still missing something in your idea?

Comment: @amit I don't know ahead of time how many nodes there will be, and that number will vary as nodes move in and out of range. I agree that exponential backoff per Aloha and Ethernet has the problem of resetting - something more like TCP's AIMD may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually a wireless mesh network, which is a whole reseach field by itself. Apart from that acknowledgement messages are a good idea. You can piggyback them with the announcements themselves if packet overhead is a concern. They allow to distinguish between collisions and background noise by observing how many neighbors answered and allow basic rate limiting by waiting until (most) neighbors acknowledge each transmission (stop-and-go). This gets of course even more complicated if the controllers are very mobile.

It will be very hard (and probably not desirable) to maintain a equal update rate over the whole network, because transmission quality can vary wildly in different areas and points in time.